# BS4 Cards in React with reactstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, bootstrap-4, jsx, reactstrap

Couple of question on using cards within React.

First, based on the below code, why does these 4 cards not sit next to one another? Did I forget to apply something or another?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Card, CardText, CardImg, CardBody, CardLink,
  CardTitle, Button, Col, Row } from 'reactstrap';

class Users extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <Card>
              <CardImg top width="25%" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=318%C3%97180&w=318&h=180" alt="Card image cap" />
              <CardBody>
                <CardTitle>Need Help Finding Customers?</CardTitle>
                <CardText>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</CardText>
                <Button>Button</Button>
              </CardBody>
              </Card>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <Card>
              <CardImg top width="25%" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=318%C3%97180&w=318&h=180" alt="Card image cap" />
              <CardBody>
                <CardTitle>Get help with a Moneyball activity!</CardTitle>
                <CardText>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</CardText>
                <Button>Button</Button>
              </CardBody>
              </Card>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <Card>
              <CardImg top width="25%" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=318%C3%97180&w=318&h=180" alt="Card image cap" />
              <CardBody>
                <CardTitle>Request Moneyball in-person training</CardTitle>
                <CardText>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</CardText>
                <Button>Button</Button>
              </CardBody>
              </Card>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <Card>
              <CardImg top width="25%" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=318%C3%97180&w=318&h=180" alt="Card image cap" />
              <CardBody>
                <CardTitle>Register for an Immerse Event</CardTitle>
                <CardText>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</CardText>
                <Button>Button</Button>
              </CardBody>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Users;
```

What I am getting is this:

[image]

Additionally, going by examples I see on the web, I like the concept of cards, but would prefer to make the entire card like a large button. Within React, what is some best practices with this?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

The elements for the 'grid' system (Container, Row, Col) seem to be missing from reactstrap's docs, but taking a quick look at the code for the Col component I'd say you need to add a property for the desired size.

Something like this:

```
<Col lg="2">
```

for the 'col-lg-2' bootstrap class, or

```
<Col sm="true">
```

for the 'col-sm' class, without number.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Thinking further, I forgot to load `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';` into my `index.js`.